# Variance and second moment

Tags: variance

I am encountering times when Var(X) is interchanged with $E[X^2]$ where X is a random variable and in the cases where E[X] = 0 I see why that is:
$Var(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$.
 But sometimes that is not the case, i.e. E[X] != 0. Would you mind weighing in? Take for example this problem:
Customers arrive at a restaurant with a Poisson rate $\lambda$ and on average spend 20 dollars with a variance of 5. What is the mean and variance of the revenue at this restaurant over 10 hours?
The solution goes as follows:
Let $X_i$ be money spent by i-th customer and let N(t) be customer arrivals by time t.
average money spent = $E[\sum_{i=1}^{N(10)}X_i = E[N(10)]*E[X_i]$
=$10*\lambda*20 $, this is clear

variance = $Var(\sum_{i=1}^{N(10)}X_i) = 10*\lambda*E[X_i^2]$
= $10*\lambda * (Var(X_i) + E[X_i]^2)$

1. the expectation was computed to be 200*$\lambda$
2. In the first step of the variance calculation they seemingly skipped a step that most likely was as follows:
   variance = $Var(\sum_{i=1}^{N(10)}X_i) = E[N(10)]*Var[X_i]$
   and then they substituted $Var(X_i) = E[X_i^2]$

   How come? I'm not fully following why that is allowed.

Comment: It is always the case that $\operatorname{var} X = E X^2 - (EX)^2$.

Comment: Look up Wald's equation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the very first comment by copper.hat answered this simple question more than six years ago.

Answer (score 0):

First the average. Let me use $M$ instead of $N(10)$. We have $E M = 10 \lambda$,
of course.
\begin{eqnarray}
E[ \sum_{k=1}^M X_k ] &=& E [ E [\sum_{k=1}^M X_k | M=n]] \\
&=& E [ E [\sum_{k=1}^n X_k | M=n]] \\
&=&  \sum_n E [\sum_{k=1}^n X_k | M=n] P[M=n] \\
&=&  \sum_n n E[X] P[M=n] \\
&=& EM \cdot EX
\end{eqnarray}

Now the variance, note that 
$\operatorname{var} (\sum_{k=1}^M X_k) = E [(\sum_{k=1}^M X_k)^2] - (E [\sum_{k=1}^M X_k])^2$.

We have
\begin{eqnarray}
E[(\sum_{k=1}^M X_k)^2] &=& E[E[(\sum_{k=1}^M X_k)^2|M=n]] \\
&=& E[E[(\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k X_l|M=n]  ] \\
&=& \sum_n E[(\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k X_l|M=n]  P[M=n] \\
&=& \sum_n (n E X^2 + n(n-1)  (EX)^2 ) P[M=n] \\
&=& \sum_n (n E X^2 + n^2  (EX)^2 - n (EX)^2) P[M=n] \\
&=& EM \cdot (EX^2) + EM^2 \cdot (E X)^2 - EM \cdot (EX)^2 \\
&=& EM \cdot \operatorname{var} X + EM^2 \cdot (E X)^2
\end{eqnarray}
and so
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{var} (\sum_{k=1}^M X_k) &=& EM \cdot \operatorname{var} X + (E X)^2 (E M^2 - (EM)^2) \\
&=&  EM \cdot \operatorname{var} X + (EX)^2 \operatorname{var} M
\end{eqnarray}
Since $E M = \operatorname{var} M$, this gives
$\operatorname{var} (\sum_{k=1}^M X_k) = E M \cdot E X^2$